# Grouping and ordering a list using LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a message structure that contains the following

```
DateTime dateIn;
long? messageId;
string messageContent;
```

I am trying to group my message list based on messageId and ordered by the dateIn field.

My LINQ currently looks like this

```
var groups = from c in MessageList 
            let name = c.messageId
                orderby name ascending, c.dateIn ascending
                group c by name into g
                select g;
```

When I try and feed it back into a new List< Messages>, the compiler comes back with

> "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<
>   System.Linq.IGrouping < long?, Messages> > to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List< Messages>"

Is the problem down to the long? more than anything? I have tried to cast messageId to long, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: "When I try and feed it back into a new List< Messages>", how you are doing this, can you show us the code??

Comment: I'm assuming you're not showing us a `ToList()` call on `groups`. Why do you hope that a list of message-groups is assignable to a type that represents a flat list of messages?

Comment: I'm using List<Messages> grouped = groups.ToList(); to assign it to the new group. Apologies for not including that.

Comment: since groups have both messages and messageId, you cannot assign groups.ToList() directly to List<Messages>, you have to specify...

Comment: @Nodoid Then your should use List<long?,Messages> grouped = groups.ToList(); Your Linq grouped result has the type <long?,Messages>, so if you want to get the whole collection of groups, it should be List<long?,Messages>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what are you trying to do, there is simpler way. Look at my demo:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Message> MessageList = new List<Message>()
        {
            new Message(){ dateIn = new DateTime(2000,1,11)},
            new Message(){ dateIn = new DateTime(2000,1,9)},
            new Message(){ dateIn = new DateTime(2000,1,8), messageId = 5},
            new Message(){ dateIn = new DateTime(2000,1,12)},
            new Message(){ dateIn = new DateTime(2000,1,2), messageId = 7}
        };

        foreach (var item in MessageList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("===");

        // MUCH SIMPLER
        var result = MessageList
            .GroupBy(m => m.messageId)
            .SelectMany(m => m.ToList())
            .OrderBy(m => m.dateIn);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

struct Message
{
    public DateTime dateIn { get; set; }
    public long? messageId { get; set; }
    public string messageContent { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return messageId + "\t" + dateIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - amazing what LINQ can really do!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use SelectMany to orbitaine your Message collection from the grouped one (if I understood you correct):

```
List<Messages> back = groups.SelectMany(m=>m.ToList()).ToList();
```

**UPDATED**

According to your comments. When you use **GroupBy** - Linq creates the Enumerable of new generic type combining your collection type and key type, which you use for grouping. In your case it is Messages type and long? (the type of messageId - key, you are grouping by). So this should work for you:

```
List<long?,Messages> grouped = groups.ToList();
```

Or you can use **var** and this should work also:

```
var grouped = groups.ToList();
```